# X (java:sdk) should not link to Y (java:platform)

Tags: android-source

I am an android firmware developer. I work with source of android 9. I've written a custom network location provider for AOSP firmware, named offline location service. I've added this application to `packages/apps/offlinelocatonservice` path in AOSP build tree.

I've created an `Android.mk` file for it to include it in default packages in android OS.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := OfflineLocationService

LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true

# Include libraries

LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := framework com.android.location.provider

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-common

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := \
    android-support-v4 \
    android-support-v7-appcompat \
    android-support-design \
    android-support-v7-preference \
    android-support-v7-recyclerview \

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += --extra-packages android.support.design

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

But when I build AOSP, I encounter with this error:

```
packages/apps/OfflineLocationService/Android.mk: error: OfflineLocationService (java:sdk) should not link to com.android.location.provider (java:platform)
packages/apps/OfflineLocationService/Android.mk: error: OfflineLocationService (java:sdk) should not link to framework (java:platform)
```

Why I should not link to `com.android.location.provider` and `framework`?
In previous androids such as android 8 and earlier, this error doesn't happen.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the same problem in Android 9.0
Temporary I solved by changing `OfflineLocationService/Android.mk` replacing:

```
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
```

with:

```
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true
```

But it would be nice if anyone could find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

From Android documentation:

> Starting in Android 9 (API level 28), the platform restricts which non-SDK interfaces your app can use.

Ideally, you should rewrite your app to only use the Android public SDK.

You can read more information on this page: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

Answer (score -1):

Not directly answering the question, but for those writing a module using `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` in combination with `LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES`, this stopped working in Android 9:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
(...)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := bar
(...)
include $(BUILD_WHATEVER)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := bar:path/to/bar.jar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

This will yield `error: foo (java:sdk) should not link to bar (java:platform)`. The solution is to integrate the prebuilt JAR like this:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := bar
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := path/to/bar.jar
LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE := true

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

And then using `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` as before for referencing it from module `foo`.

For a real world example, see [how Google did it in the Dialer app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r61/Android.mk#214).

Or just use `LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true` (but that lets the module use private APIs, which could be unwanted).